# Android App - Run JavaScript function once, then not again until the app has been updated

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am making an Android PhoneGap app using JavaScript.

The App loads data from a local text file and stores it in the Local Storage and from then on the data is loaded from the Local Storage.

The problem comes when I want to update the data in the text file and have the app reload the data into the local storage again. I can't get it to load the text file once, then never again. Each time the app starts it will load the text file again until I do another update that sets localStorage.update = 0;

This is the code i've tried, but gets the above result.

```
localStorage.update = 1; //tell the app to update 
                         //but this will run each time the app is opened

if(localStorage.update == 1) {
    localStorage["StoredData"] = ""; //text file data is stored in [StoredData]

    //Proceed to load the text file into storage

    localStorage.update = 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the below code works:

```
if(localStorage.update == 1) { // change this value everytime you want to reload the file
    localStorage["StoredData"] = ""; //text file data is stored in [StoredData]

    //Proceed to load the text file into storage

    localStorage.update = 1; //set this to the same as the if statement
}
```